# WP_Query order by date in meta_value

Tags: wp-query, categories, order

i have a small problem i think.

this is my code for my category-releases.php:

```
<?php 
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => '16',
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_key'          => 'releaseDate');
    $posts = get_posts($args); 
    ?>
  <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ) ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content-releases', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

in the meta_key > releaseDate i have different dates like 13.02.2015, 02.05.2015, 12.05.2015 and so on. now i want to order the post from the meta_key like this: 30.05.2015, 28.05.2015, 10.04.2015...

i tried to set the order and used orderby but then the order is like: 11.05.2015, 02.05.2015, 27.04.2015, 02.05.2015...

someone can help me? much thanks!

Comment: Your date format is wrong, your format should be `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: PieterGoosen is correct, I would almost say that your query is treating the `meta_key` as a string and trying to order it that way but the order you've given is not what I would expect a string to be ordered by.

Comment: You're not passing along the category parameter, it's going to list all posts not just those in the releases category. Have you considered using the `pre_get_posts` filter? What you're currently doing is identical to `query_posts` and bad practice

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you! In Germany we're writing it dd-mm-YYYY is there a way to change the format?

Comment: @TomJNowell don't have tried the filter i'will take a look! tahnk you but i get only the post from that category.

Answer (score 3):

change your args as bellow

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'your_post_type',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'releaseDate')),
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'paged'      =>$paged,
);
```

If you get the results ordered other way around, change `'order' => 'DESC',` You'll get the correct order.